# How to obtain size of tiny cluster (few pixels) in R

Tags: r, image, image-processing

I have a picture of 2 colors. Black color pixels are in form of tiny cluster and represents defect. The background of the image is in white color. As observed the clusters consist of few black pixels.

I would like to know the location and max dimension of each cluster to compare with the acceptable tolerance.

I used the function `computeFeatures` as below but it does not work while it works with large clusters ([How to obtain size of cluster of pixels in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63336483/how-to-obtain-size-of-cluster-of-pixels-in-r)). Is there a way to use this function for tiny clusters or need to use another one?

```
library(EBImage)
library(ggplot2)
image <- readImage('C:/Users/Mezeix/Desktop/AI defect/export.png')
#Obtain the spots
dots_bw <- getFrame(image, 1)
labelled_dots <- bwlabel(dots_bw)
df <- as.data.frame(cbind(computeFeatures.moment(labelled_dots)[, 1:2],
                          computeFeatures.shape(labelled_dots)[, 5:6]))
df
> df
           V1       V2
m.cx 409.4894 408.5003
m.cy 840.5770 933.6126
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to adjust the size threshold using `thresh`. Here, we'll reduce it to a single pixel wide by a single pixel in height:

```r
library(EBImage)
library(ggplot2)

image <- readImage("https://i.stack.imgur.com/xBoMv.png")
dots_bw <- getFrame(image, 1)
labelled_dots <- bwlabel(thresh(getFrame(image, 1), w = 1, h = 1, offset = 0.05))
df <- as.data.frame(cbind(computeFeatures.moment(labelled_dots)[, 1:2],
                          computeFeatures.shape(labelled_dots)[, 5:6]))
```

Now we can see we have detected 37 dots:

```r
df
#>         m.cx      m.cy s.radius.min s.radius.max
#> 1  103.87500  194.8750    1.6505891     2.885211
#> 2  185.34375  269.7812    2.1573875     4.965312
#> 3  561.00000  274.0000    1.0000000     6.082763
#> 4  733.50000  285.5000    1.5811388     2.121320
#> 5  253.00000  294.0000    1.9452379     3.682625
#> 6  729.47727  314.4773    2.4561921     8.833622
#> 7   56.13333  349.3667    1.8537490     5.975973
#> 8  373.72222  458.1667    1.8350274     6.086439
#> 9  511.55000  494.7500    2.4224070     7.563160
#> 10 166.40000  538.1667    0.7187361     5.838494
#> 11 773.85714  588.8571    1.8242386     5.493605
#> 12 771.50000  597.5000    1.5811388     2.121320
#> 13 592.50000  643.0000    1.5000000     2.500000
#> 14 796.64286  654.1429    1.3585168     8.230450
#> 15 527.26190  669.0952    1.7619466     7.479458
#> 16 239.00000  681.5000    1.1180340     4.609772
#> 17 226.07143  698.2143    1.1947865     5.065401
#> 18 463.00000  749.0000    1.0000000     7.071068
#> 19 211.00000  753.1000    1.0000000     6.082763
#> 20 469.50000  765.5000    1.5811388     3.807887
#> 21  80.13636  775.8636    0.9337463     8.945096
#> 22 103.00000  837.0000    1.0000000     4.123106
#> 23 410.00000  908.0000    1.0000000     4.123106
#> 24 410.00000  917.5000    1.1180340     1.802776
#> 25 177.50000  919.0000    1.1180340     1.802776
#> 26 639.00000  932.0000    1.0000000     3.162278
#> 27 145.50000  999.5000    2.5495098     3.535534
#> 28 493.00000 1004.5000    1.1180340     3.640055
#> 29 602.50000 1110.0000    1.5000000     3.354102
#> 30 224.00000 1125.5000    1.1180340     2.692582
#> 31 712.00000 1136.0000    1.0000000     3.162278
#> 32 380.00000 1159.0000    1.0000000     3.162278
#> 33 699.72222 1211.7778    1.4528340     3.279906
#> 34 692.00000 1215.5000    1.1180340     4.609772
#> 35 620.50000 1214.0000    1.1180340     1.802776
#> 36 520.00000 1282.0000    1.0000000     2.236068
#> 37 524.50000 1340.5000    1.5811388     2.121320
```

And we can plot their sizes using `ggplot`:

```r
img_df <- reshape2::melt(as.matrix(as.raster(as.array(image))))

ggplot(img_df, aes(Var1, Var2, fill = value)) + 
  geom_raster() +
  scale_fill_identity() +
  scale_y_reverse() +
  geom_text(inherit.aes = FALSE, data = df, color = "red",
            aes(x = m.cx, y = m.cy, label = round(s.radius.max, 1))) +
  coord_equal()
```

[image]