# How to obtain size of cluster in matrix (R)

Tags: r, matrix

I have a matrix and I would like to know the center and min/max size of each cluster represented by the same number value. By example, to get the center position and size of the cluster represented by the number 2 in the following matrix. The idea is closed to the one perform on an image [How to obtain size of cluster of pixels in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63336483/how-to-obtain-size-of-cluster-of-pixels-in-r)

```
> read.csv("4c_class.csv")
   X1 X1.1 X1.2 X1.3 X1.4 X1.5 X1.6 X3 X3.1 X3.2
1   1    1    1    1    1    1    1  3    3    3
2   1    1    1    1    1    1    1  3    3    3
3   1    1    1    1    1    1    1  1    1    3
4   1    1    1    1    1    1    1  1    1    1
5   1    1    1    1    1    1    1  1    1    1
6   4    1    1    1    1    1    1  1    1    1
7   4    1    1    1    1    1    2  1    1    1
8   4    1    1    1    1    1    2  1    1    1
9   4    1    1    1    1    2    2  2    1    1
10  4    4    1    1    1    2    2  2    2    1
11  4    4    1    1    1    1    2  2    2    1
12  4    4    1    1    1    1    2  2    2    1
13  4    4    1    1    1    1    2  2    2    1
14  4    4    1    1    1    1    1  2    2    1
15  4    4    1    1    1    1    1  2    1    1
16  4    4    4    1    1    1    1  2    1    1
17  4    4    4    4    1    1    1  1    1    1
18  4    4    4    4    4    4    1  1    1    1
19  4    4    4    4    4    4    1  1    1    1
```

Comment: Maybe make a rollback to the original question as now the topic is now somehow different and make a new question with this new topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `which` and set `arr.ind = TRUE` to get the positions where the matrix has a specific value. With this positions the `range` or `mean` could be calculated.

```
y <- which(x == 2, TRUE)

apply(y, 2, range) #Range
#     row col
#[1,]   7   6
#[2,]  16   9

apply(y, 2, mean) #Center
#      row       col 
#11.318182  7.727273
```

Comment: Thanks, is there a way to get each cluster independently?