# How to calculate size and location of multi clusters in matrix (R)

Tags: r, matrix

I have a matrix and I would like to know the center and min/max size of each cluster represented by the same number value.

By example, to get the center position and size of clusters (or the min/max column/row) represented by the number 2 in the following matrix. The idea is closed to the one perform on an image [How to obtain size of cluster of pixels in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63336483/how-to-obtain-size-of-cluster-of-pixels-in-r) and [How to obtain size of multi clusters in matrix (R)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68279953/how-to-obtain-size-of-multi-clusters-in-matrix-r)

But when I use the function `apply(matrix2, 2, mean)` and `apply(matrix2, 2, range)`, results merge the two clusters. Is there a way to get each cluster ?

```
> matrix<- read.csv("2_ind_matrix.csv")
   X1 X1.1 X1.2 X1.3 X1.4 X1.5
1   1    1    1    1    1    1
2   1    1    1    1    1    1
3   1    1    1    1    1    1
4   1    1    1    2    2    2
5   1    1    1    1    2    2
6   1    1    1    1    1    1
7   1    1    1    1    1    1
8   1    1    1    1    1    1
9   1    1    1    1    1    1
10  1    1    1    1    1    1
11  2    1    1    1    1    1
12  2    1    1    1    1    1
13  2    1    1    1    1    1
14  2    2    1    1    1    1
15  2    2    2    1    1    1
16  2    2    2    2    2    2
17  2    2    2    2    2    2

> matrix2<- which(matrix == 2, TRUE)
> apply(matrix2, 2, range) #Range
     row col
[1,]   4   1
[2,]  17   6
> apply(matrix2, 2, mean) #Center
  row   col 
13.16  3.20
```

Comment: Your question is not clear. Wht exacly do you want? The mean of the positions or the mean? You just used the which function. Is that not okay?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The decision on how many clusters are there needs to be done. Here I assume there are 2 clusters. Those can be found by `kmeans` by using the positions returned from `which`.

```
y <- which(x==2, TRUE)
y <- cbind(y, cluster=kmeans(y, 2)$cluster)

aggregate(y[,1:2], list(y[,3]), range)
#  Group.1 row.1 row.2 col.1 col.2
#1       1     4     5     4     6
#2       2    11    17     1     6

aggregate(y[,1:2], list(y[,3]), mean)
#  Group.1   row col
#1       1  4.40 5.2
#2       2 15.35 2.7
```

Comment: Thanks. But I have a problem using kmeans when there are lot of clusters. The clusters are not well detected. Pixels far from each other are considered part of the same cluster. By example cluster located at (1,1)  is regrouped with the cluster (7,6).

Comment: Maybe you can try different `algorithm` in `kmeans` or use another clustering method.